# Eclipse installing google app engine sdk problems

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I am trying to install Google App Engine SDK and a few other plugins on Eclipse using the steps in the following
  link: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3

But I keep getting this error:

"An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,com.google.appengine.eclipse.sdkbundle,1.8.7.
No space left on device"

Does anyone know what that error means, cause I haven't been able to find it on the web? 
 And also, "No space left on device" - What exactly does that imply; there's plenty of space on the    disk.

Comment: Where are u trying to install it?

Comment: On Eclipse - exactly the same way as laid out in the link I referred to :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have enough disk space on a partition where eclipse in installed.

Comment: I am using Archlinux and I didn't partition the disk when installing it. This is weird.

Comment: What's the output of `df -h` on your system?

Comment: I copied the first line as the size is probably what matters most now:

  Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
  /dev/sda1        98G   27G   67G  29% /

To make it more clear, only 27G is used.